# Regression Model in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, standardization

I'm new to python and trying to perform a random forest regression task.
I import my dataset that has 5 columns in total (including date column). My data is time dependant so i cannot use the train/test split. So instead i do the following

```
feature_cols = [ 'Rainfall' ,'Temperature','Usage amount']
target_v = df['water levels']
X = df[feature_cols] 
y = target_v
```

then i use the time series split in sklearn to split my data into train and test

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
tss = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 3)
for train_index, test_index in tss.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index, :], X.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

Now i need to perform preprocessing such as scaling my data and removing the mean (detrend). So my question is what am i supposed to do first? i.e. do i remove the mean first then scale my data or i first scale then remove the mean?

Also do i perform the 2 techniques on my entire dataframe (df) or on a subset of my data (i.e. just on the training data)? If it's a subset how do i do this?

Here is an example of scaling and mean removal i had tried on my entire dataframe

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)

mean = np.mean((df.values), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
detrended = df - mean
```

Then i used detrended dataframe for spliting my data into train and test and ran my models. Am not sure if this is the correct approach?